# PyMongo, handling fields with time relative to the database time

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Say I have a document field name "creation_time". I would like to have its value initialized with the **database current time**, instead using the client machine time with:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

How can I achieve this with PyMongo?

Moreover is there any way to do operations during the field initialization, for example:

"creation_time": magic_get_mongodb_time() + 10 hours

As a side note I'm OK to handle unix timestamps, not necessary datetime format.

EDIT: operations on dates are not possible yet (May 2015): https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3174

Comment: Worth mentioning that at some time, using the [`eval` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) would have been the answer to run arbitrary JS code on the server. But is is deprecated as of MongoDB 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the MongoDB's [**`$currentdate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator in your update, this sets the value of a field to the current date, either as a **[Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date)** or a **[timestamp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-timestamp)**. The default type is Date.

```
db = con['test']            
test = db.test
test.update({}, { 
    '$currentDate': {
        'creation_time': { '$type': 'timestamp' }
    }
},upsert=True)
```